# How do I reshape data by groups? (Stata)

Tags: stata

I need some help with reshaping some data into groups. The variables are country1 and country2, and samegroup, which indicates if the countries are in the same group (continent). The original data I have is something like this:

| country1 | country2 | samegroup |
| --- | --- | --- |
| China | Vietnam | 1 |
| France | Italy | 1 |
| Brazil | Argentina | 1 |
| Argentina | Brazil | 1 |
| Australia | US | 0 |
| US | Australia | 0 |
| Vietnam | China | 1 |
| Vietnam | Thailand | 1 |
| Thailand | Vietnam | 1 |
| Italy | France | 1 |

And I would like the output to be this:

| country | group |
| --- | --- |
| China | 1 |
| Vietnam | 1 |
| Thailand | 1 |
| Italy | 2 |
| France | 2 |
| Brazil | 3 |
| Argentina | 3 |
| Australia | 4 |
| US | 5 |

My first instinct would be to sort the initial data by "samegroup", then reshape (long to wide). But that doesn't quite solve the issue and I'm not sure how to continue from there. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a non-standard definition of continent, it is much easier to use `kountry` (which you will probably have to install) than `reshape` or repeated `merge`s:

```
clear
input str12 country1 str12  country2 byte   samegroup
China   Vietnam 1
France  Italy   1
Brazil  Argentina   1
Argentina   Brazil  1
Australia   US  0
US  Australia   0
Vietnam China   1
Vietnam Thailand    1
Thailand    Vietnam 1
Italy   France  1
end

capture net install dm0038_1
kountry country1, from(other) geo(marc) marker
rename (country1 GEO) (country group)
sort group country
capture ssc install sencode
sencode group, replace // or use recode here 
keep country group 
duplicates drop 
list, clean noobs
label list group
```

This will produce

```
 . list, clean noobs

      country           group  
        China            Asia  
     Thailand            Asia  
      Vietnam            Asia  
    Australia     Australasia  
       France          Europe  
        Italy          Europe  
           US   North America  
    Argentina   South America  
       Brazil   South America  

    . label list group
    group:
               1 Asia
               2 Australasia
               3 Europe
               4 North America
               5 South America
```